# Chat GPT API incomplete response React.js

Tags: reactjs, request, chatgpt-api, gpt-3

I'm implementing a chat for my web app and I'm not getting the complete response of chat gpt in some cases. When the prompt is about giving a list it doesn't work correctly, for example if I ask for the top 3 richest countries the response is `the top 3 richest countries are:` and it stays like that. I can't figure out how the response that it gives me is incomplete, I tried playing with the tokens but it didn't work. I don't know what the problem is, I'm making the request directly from React this way:

```js
export async function generateChatResponse(prompt: string): Promise<string> {
  try {
    console.log(prompt)
    const response = await axios.post(
      API_BASE_URL,
      {
        messages: [
          {
            role: 'user',
            content: prompt
          }
        ],
        model:'gpt-3.5-turbo',
        max_tokens: 150,
        temperature: 0.7,
        stop: '\n',
      },
      {
        headers: {
          'Content-Type': 'application/json',
          'Authorization': `Bearer ${API_KEY}`,
        },
      }
    );
    console.log(response)
    return response.data.choices[0].message.content.trim();
  } catch (error) {
    console.error('Error generating chat response:', error);
    return 'Oops! An error occurred while processing your request.';
  }
}
```

Comment: Specifically in your code, does `response` contain that one line of text, or does the return value of this function contain that one line of text?  If the latter, what does `response` contain?

Comment: @David response contains the line of text, I checked the log and it is the only message shown in the request.